# How to get multiple email addresses via regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the regex pattern I'm using which works fine but only returns one match in the resulting array.

`([a-zA-Z0-9+._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)`

snippet:

```
var re = '([a-zA-Z0-9+._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)';
var s = {a:12, b: 'asdasd@asd.com', c:'as123@asd.com'};
var x = JSON.stringify(s);
var z = x.match(re);
console.log(z);
> Array ["asdasd@asd.com", "asdasd@asd.com"]
```

Expected: Array ["asdasd@asd.com", "as123@asd.com"]
I would like an array with just the matched email addresses. I tried a global match by adding a trailing /g but the result I get is null.

`/([a-zA-Z0-9+._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/g`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your regex also seems to be missing the starting delimiter. `/pattern/g`

Comment: I added a snippet; I tried with the pattern/g but I get null. Maybe I'm not using it correctly?

Comment: No, you're missing both sides.

Comment: Please see the last line of my description to see what I had tried.

Comment: I figured out the problem; it was the redundant quotes around the regex.